# Why can't I concatenate these JS functions?

Tags: javascript, input, syntax

If, in a function in onclick, I say:

```
offset=parseFloat(document.getElementById("offsetId").value); //value=-2
center=sp+offset; // sp is a float == 190
alert("center="+center);
```

I get "center=190[object HTMLInputElement]"

If I separate the functions as:

```
offset=document.getElementById("offsetId"); 
offset=parseFloat(offset.value);
center=sp+offset;
alert("center="+center);
```

I get the same error.

But if I do it this way

```
offset=document.getElementById("offsetId"); 
center=sp+parseFloat(offset.value);
alert("center="+center);
```

I get the right answer, center=188.

Why can't I concatenate the functions as in the first 2 examples?
They seem identical to me.

EDIT:
Here is sample code which produces the "impossible" results:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title> New Document </title>
</head>

<body>
<script>sp=parseFloat(190.); </script>
<!-- same result with sp=190.;  sp=Number(190.); sp=Number("190."); -->

<form>
    <p>Enter Offset   <input id="offsetId" type="text" name="offset" value=0> <!-- eg -2 -->
    <p> 
    <input 
    type="button" 
    name="go"
    value="Do the Plot"
        onclick='
            alert("at19: sp = "+sp+", typeof sp=", typeof sp);  
                            // shows: at19: sp = 190, typeof sp=
            offset=parseFloat(document.getElementById("offsetId").value); 
            alert("at22, offset="+offset+", typeof offset="+typeof offset);
    // shows: at23, offset=[object HTMLInputElement], typeof offset=object
            center=sp+offset;
            alert("at25: center="+center);
            // shows: at24: center=190[object HTMLInputElement]

// alternate 1
            offset = parseFloat(offset.value);
            center=sp+offset;
            alert("at31: offset="+offset+", center="+center);
// shows: at31: offset=[object HTMLInputElement], center=190[object HTMLInputElement]

// alternate 2
            offset=document.getElementById("offsetId"); 
            center=sp+parseFloat(offset.value);
            alert("at37: offset="+offset+", center="+center);
// shows: at36: offset=[object HTMLInputElement], center=188
        '
        >
    </form>     
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that the last method gives the correct answer.
I suspect that I can't get sp to show a type may be significant.

Comment: Neither the [first](https://jsfiddle.net/pdk6L6r4/) or [second](https://jsfiddle.net/pdk6L6r4/1/) examples produce the output you claim it does. It is impossible for `parseFloat` to return an HTML element, or a string representing an HTML element, or any other value that would produce the output in your question. Please include a working sample that reproduces your problem. Use the in-built code editor.

Comment: I give an example (now a complete program) that gives output so unusual that you claim it is impossible, and you think that it's not worth posting? Kindly look at the program I've posted, along with the "impossible" alert output.

Comment: The onus is on you to provide code that reproduces your problem, and you **had** failed to do that. Now that you've produced code that **does** reproduce you problem, the problem and solution are obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared your variables, so `offset` isn't what you think it is.

Within the context of your event handler, `offset` is a reference to the `<input name="offset">` already defined by the form.

If you're going to shadow the existing variable with a local variable of the same name, you need to declare it with `var offset`.

```html
<script>sp=parseFloat(190.); </script>
<!-- same result with sp=190.;  sp=Number(190.); sp=Number("190."); -->

<form>
    <p>Enter Offset   <input id="offsetId" type="text" name="offset" value=0> <!-- eg -2 -->
    <p> 
    <input 
    type="button" 
    name="go"
    value="Do the Plot"
        onclick='
            var offset = parseFloat(document.getElementById("offsetId").value); 
            alert("at22, offset="+offset+", typeof offset="+typeof offset);
        '
        >
    </form>
```